# Shakespeare, snowflakes and soccer balls

Tags: word-property, connect-wall

[image]

Text version:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SNOWFLAKE | SANCTION | SHAKESPEARE | SOCCER BALL |
| COLOSSUS | GEOMETRY | DUST | SCREW NUT |
| GARDENS | AFTERNOON | HONEYCOMB | SEED |
| BUSINESS | MAUSOLEUM | LEFT | LIGHTHOUSE |

CSV version:

```
SNOWFLAKE, SANCTION, SHAKESPEARE, SOCCER BALL
COLOSSUS, GEOMETRY, DUST, SCREW NUT
GARDENS, AFTERNOON, HONEYCOMB, SEED
BUSINESS, MAUSOLEUM, LEFT, LIGHTHOUSE
```

**What are the 4 groups of 4 words each and how the words are connected to each other in each group?**

Hint for the 4th group:

> The tag [word-property](/questions/tagged/word-property) has been added as a hint.

Comment: Well, you should answer this. What is the criteria for each group? How is each group connected?

Comment: @MikeQ, Each group of 4 words is connected by something. And, no, the words are not connected by the column/row they are on. Similar questions with the same tag have been asked before and each group has a theme that connects the words.

Comment: Understood. It would have been helpful to restate the rules, though. Anyway I removed my earlier comments.

Comment: No problem. :) I guess I thought that was clear from the type of puzzle. But I should have explained it anyway. I reworded the question itself - hopefully, it is more clear now to anyone who sees the puzzle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mike Q has found the first two groups.

The third group might be ...

> ... words that can have opposite meanings:
>
>  • to **sanction** can mean to approve of or to punish;
>  • to **dust** can mean to sprinkle with dust (or sugar) or to remove dust;
>  • to **seed** can mean to place seeds or to remove seeds (from fruit);
>  • **left** can mean still there or having gone.

The last group is:

> **Shakespeare**, **geometry**, **afternoon** and **business**: Each of those words has an A-Z sum of 108. (The A-Z sum is the sum of the letter values, where a letter's value is its position in the alphabet: A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, and so on until Z = 26.)

Comment: You are right for the third group. Now only the last group needs its pattern. :)

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest "school" somewhere, but I don't think it fits these particular words, as in "business school", "afternoon school", school of shakespeare, but I don't get geometry into that

Comment: Yes, you are correct. So how can I accept an answer? @MikeQ has 2 groups correct and you have the other 2? :)

Comment: I decided to accept this answer as it gives credit to first 2 groups that have been solved by Mike Q and to just mark the puzzle as solved. :) Hopefully, this is OK with you both.

Comment: @Maria: Thanks, I'm fine with the tick. `:)` (But I wouldn't mind if it went to Mike. If you want a really neutral solution, write and accept your own answer where you credit the partial answers.)

Answer (score 7):

Partial answer

Group 1

> The 7 ancient wonders of the world:
>  * **[Colossus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossus_of_Rhodes)** of Rhodes
>  * Hanging **[Gardens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanging_Gardens_of_Babylon)** of Babylon
>  * **[Lighthouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lighthouse_of_Alexandria)** of Alexandria
>  * **[Mausoleum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mausoleum_at_Halicarnassus)** at Halicarnassus

Group 2

> Stuff related to hexagonal patterns:
>  * A **Snowflake** will typically have [hexagonal structure](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/446/why-do-snowflakes-form-into-hexagonal-structures).
>  * A **Soccer ball** has hexagons and pentagons on its surface.
>  * A **Honeycomb** consists of hexagonal holes.
>  * A **Screw nut** is a hexagon with a circular hole.

Comment: Except that the second in your group 2 doesn't actually fit your description of that group.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος The groups are correct and soccer balls are actually made of hexagons and pentagons: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ec/Soccer_ball.svg

Answer (score -1):

For the remaining set of words (though a partial answer),

> Perhaps, all are linked with the number **12**

As,

> Shakespeare has written a play called *The Twelfth Night*,
>  Time is denoted as afternoon only after 12:00 hrs noon,
>  Business has 12 golden rules for success (attributed to Forbes)
>  Geometry... is perhaps the one that may not be linked with 12 properly, thoug there are few posts stating that **it** is a framework number that decides the shape of universe geometrically !

Comment: That's implausible enough that it encourages me to reveal one of my rejected candidates: Remove the first two letters and the last three and you get a word. TERN and SIN are obvious enough. OME is the opposite of "emo" and amazingly AKESPE is a place in Kazakhstan!  Unfortunately LOS and REW are genuine words too: one doesn't even need to go to Urban Dictionary or the atlas! :D